# Read and Display single product data based using Product ID- Angular 8 and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch a single product record from the fire store by angular 8 but not understanding how to get the record. I am new to this please help me I spend 2 days in this. Below is my Fire store database. As I displayed all products on one page and from this page when I click on a particular production another page details for that respective product must be shown.

[image: database]

**This my TS file.**

```
private ProductID;
private ProductData:ProductDModel[];
 
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private empservice : GoodsService,private GoodService : GoodsService,public afs:AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  
this.ProductID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("ProductID");
this.GoodService.getSingleGoodData(this.ProductID).catch(data => {
  this.ProductData = data.map(e => { 
    alert(this.ProductData);       
      return {
        
       ProductID: e.payload.doc.data()['ProductID'],
       ProductDescription: e.payload.doc.data()['ProductDescription'],
       ProductURL:e.payload.doc.data()['ProductURL'] , 
       ProductName   :e.payload.doc.data()['ProductName']   ,
       ProductPrize:e.payload.doc.data()["ProductPrize"]
      } as unknown as ProductDModel;
    })
    console.log(this.ProductData);
   
    return this.ProductData;
    
  });"

**This is my service :**


  "public getSingleGoodData(ProductID) {

console.log(this.afs.collection('FarmerInfo').doc('Product').collection('ProductCollectionInfo',ref => ref.where('ProductID', '==', ProductID)));
    return this.afs.collection('FarmerInfo').doc('Product').collection('ProductCollectionInfo',ref => ref.where('ProductID', '==', ProductID))
    
}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try first register firestore `listener`, so in the component write:

```
let productId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("ProductID");

this.yourProductService
  .registerListener(productId)
  .subscribe(product => {
    console.log(product);
  });
```

in the service you should have:

```
registerListener(productId: string) {
   this.jobDoc = this.afs.doc<Product>(`ProductCollectionInfo/${productId}`);
   this.product = this.jobDoc.valueChanges();

   return this.product;
}
```

then you can use `this.product` whenever you want, for example you can take latest product value using following lines in service:

```
getLatest(): Observable<Product> {
   return this.job.pipe(take(1));
}
```

Good luck :)